# How to get y axis label name when i clicked on it in chartjs chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a chart.js chart.  How to get the y axis label name when I clicked on it.

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

[image]

I am expecting the answer '12' when I clicked on marked area in chart (see chart image)

The link given in the duplicate question is not working on new version of chart.js.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+label+click+chart.js+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan I changed the post

Comment: The dupe was not hard to find

Comment: @mplungjan answer given in duplicate section is not working for latest version of chartjs

Comment: Perhaps ask here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues